# API 23 Manifest.permission.READ_SMS is always denied

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I'm having a little trouble with Android 6 dangerous permissions feature, where the user has to explicitly grant some permissions. In my case, I request for an array of permissions with the following code:

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends BaseActivity implements
    RefreshClientOptionsTask.IRefreshClientOptionsListener {

        private static final String [] DANGEROUS_PERMISSIONS = {permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
            permission.READ_SMS,
            permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            permission.CALL_PHONE,
            permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            permission.CAMERA
        };

        private void initPermissions() {
            List<String> missingPermissions = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(String permission : DANGEROUS_PERMISSIONS) {
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    missingPermissions.add(permission);
                }
            }

            if (missingPermissions.size() > 0) {
                String [] permissions = new String[missingPermissions.size()];
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        missingPermissions.toArray(permissions),
                        1);
            } else {
                // we have all permissions, move on
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            for(int grantResult : grantResults) {
                // handle denied permissions
            }
        }
}
```

When this code executes I'm presented with four permission request dialogs. After I press 'allow' in every dialog `onRequestPermissionsResult` is executed and `grantResults` argument contains all zeroes (`PERMISSION_GRANTED`) except for `READ_SMS` permission - it's equal to -1 (`PERMISSION_DENIED`). What's happening and how should I handle this situation?

I'm testing on a physical device running Android 6.0.

Comment: You do have the `READ_SMS` permission specified in the manifest as well, yes?

Comment: @MikeM, what a scatterbrain I am. I had `READ_PHONE_SMS` in the manifest instead of `READ_SMS`. Please, post this as an answer, so I can accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with Marshmallow's new permissions model, any required permission must be listed in the manifest, in addition to requesting the dangerous permissions at runtime.

In this case, it seems that you effectively did not have the `READ_SMS` permission in the manifest, which is why it was denied at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Android changed permission accept in Latest **23 API level**,In This Process Some permission that will be automatically granted at install time those are specify in **Manifest** ,Remaining Permission's Are Accept's in RunTime , Because So many bad guys trying to collect user's personal data through this security weakness So Android Change's to  Runtime Permission

For More About Runtime Permission
**Check The Below Link**

[Everything every Android Developer must know about new Android's Runtime Permission](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)